# appengine.application.create permission missing

Tags: google-app-engine

Trying to create a new GAE app using gcloud:

```
gcloud app create --region "us-central"
```

Getting:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Operation not allowed
>   - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
>     description: The "appengine.applications.create" permission is required.

The service account has Project Editor and all App Engine roles, but looking in IAM there's actually no "appengine.application.create" permission:

[image]
This was from a VM.
Opening Cloud Shell in the same project and typing the same command, I get:

> The project [xxx] already contains an App Engine application. You can deploy your application using `gcloud app deploy`

How can I delete the existing GAE app so that I can create one and how can I create a GAE app from my VM - basically how to add that "create" permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can only create GAE once in a region that cannot be changed. This is what google says:

Important: Each GCP project can contain only a single App Engine application and you cannot change the region after you create the App Engine application.

See e.g. here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/managing-projects-apps-billing